# mongodb sort and regex query in efficient way

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
    db.location.find(
     { "$or": [ 
         { "country_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "country" }, 
         { "region_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "region" }, 
         { "city_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "city" } 
    ]}, 
    { "country": 1, "region": 1, "city": 1, "docType" :1 }
   ).sort({ "country_lc" :1, "region_lc": 1, "city_lc":1 })
```

this is query in monodb is taking very much time. How to query this efficiently ? Below is the explain() output of the above query. I have total 442161 documents in the collection location.I have to do some prefix searching.I have done indexing in (country_lc,docType) ,(region_lc,docType),(city_lc,docType) and (country_lc,region_lc,city_lc). My mongo version is 2.4.9.

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor country_lc_1_region_lc_1_city_lc_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 29,
"nscannedObjects" : 76935,
"nscanned" : 442161,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 76935,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 442161,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 79,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 81531,
"indexBounds" : {
    "country_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "region_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "city_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "prashanta:27017"

}
```

Comment: Could you post your explain() output?

Comment: It was actually a silly ask. The query explain as requested by @RobertoReale is quite irrelevant. As I have explained, it just does not make a difference.

Comment: ironically, you will get better performance if you remove index on   (country_lc,region_lc,city_lc).

Comment: are you sure your query is correct?  Can you include a sample document?  Does it really include fields "country_lc" and "country" and "region", "region_lc" and "city" and "city_lc" all in a single document?  And yet it has a single document type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) on the `country_lc`, `region_lc` and `city_lc` fields:

```
db.reviews.ensureIndex( { "country_lc": "text" } )
db.reviews.ensureIndex( { "region_lc": "text" } )
db.reviews.ensureIndex( { "city_lc": "text" } )
```

*Text indices* are a new feature in MongoDB 2.4.  They were added to support text search of string content in documents of a collection.  Please take a look at the official documentation for performance hints.

Moreover, you can give a try at rewriting the query as

```
db.location.find(
     { "docType": {"$in": [ "country", "region", "city" ]},
       "$or": [
         { "country_lc": /^unit/ },
         { "region_lc": /^unit/ },
         { "city_lc": /^unit/ },
       ]
    }, 
    { "country": 1, "region": 1, "city": 1, "docType" :1 }
   ).sort({ "country_lc" :1, "region_lc": 1, "city_lc":1 })
```

(**Caution**: This is, or isn't, equivalent to your query, depending on the structure of the documents.)

Comment: if I concatenate city_lc,region_lc and country_lc and add a new field in the collection and do prefix search ( using regex), will that optimize my query ??

Answer (score 0):

Now I happen to know you are running 2.4.9 which means you do not have index inter-sectioning and `$or`s cannot use sorted index. This answer *might* be different with that, which is in 2.6.

There are multiple problems with your query and it is considered a "bad" query in MongoDB, aside from the regex.

Ok, let's take the sort, in 2.4.9 sorts on `$or` will not use an index correctly ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205 ) which means that you do not have `scanAndOrder` but you do have a `nscanned` count going on multiple times of your collection size.

The `nscanned` is 442,161 to be precise, since an `$or` is in fact many queries run ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes ) at the same time whose results are merged and then returned, you can see this proof in using more than one index on a `$or` even in 2.4.9.

I cannot see what indexes your clauses are using but I will assume those might not be fitting into an index either.

The problem is that 2.4.9 simply cannot do `$or` and sort with proper indexes. You must choose between either indexing the `$or` or the sort and even then only partially covering the query.

You have a couple of things you can do to fix this:

- Upgrade to 2.6 where `$or` and sort can use an index
- Even in 2.6 you might have problems due to the added `docType` field. You could try adding it to your index right after `country_lc`, however you might also be able to add it to the end of the index and it will work OK, but bare in mind that it will scan all entries below your matches in `country_lc`.
- You might be able to take advantage of index inter-sectioning in 2.6 to get around this problem with each or clause but as the documentation states ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-and-sort-operations ) `$or` specific indexes will be dropped so I don't think this will work.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter which way you shake it, this is a horrible query that will always result in a full collection scan, or at least a full index scan.

Simply on this one document:

```js
{
    "country_lc" : "unitize",
    "region_lc" : "unitmost",
    "city_lc" : "unitleast"
}
```

The query cannot possibly anchor on any position in the index as no matter how you organize the order of the fields as indexed none of them will ever match due to the "exclusive" ( as in excluding everything ) nature of the **`$or`** operator.

So none of these approaches or other combinations will actually include an index:

```js
db.location.ensureIndex({
    "country_lc" : 1,
    "region_lc" : 1,
    "city_lc" : 1
})

db.location.ensureIndex({
    "region_lc" : 1,
    "city_lc" : 1,
    "country_lc" : 1
})

db.location.ensureIndex({
    "region_lc" : 1,
    "country_lc" : 1,
    "city_lc" : 1
})
```

Even if you **`.hint()`** the query it cannot possibly find a range,and this is again due to the "exclusive" nature:

```js
db.location.find(
    { "$or": [
        { "country_lc": /^unit/ },
        { "region_lc": /^unit/ },
        { "city_lc": /^unit/ }
    ]}
).hint(
    { country_lc: 1, region_lc: 1, city_lc: 1 }
).explain()
```

All I can think is that you really do not actually mean "words that begin as 'unit'" and you actually mean something else.

This is not just a MongoDB thing, this is a horrible thing to ask of any database engine.

You probably really want a "text search" engine that is specialized instead.

### EDIT

Some people have posted uninformed responses so I think I will actualy post the explain output from the queries that are suggested:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor country_lc_1_region_lc_1_city_lc_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "country_lc" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "region_lc" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ],
            "city_lc" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

This clearly shows that even with an index selected you cannot possibly match anything within the index bounds.

And in further regard to the false comments that have been made, this query explain response comes from the 2.6 release of MongoDB. And is also repllicated in the current nightly builds.

Comment: yes this is an eaxample query. I am doing actualy prefix searching.

Comment: An or in many DBs would be exclusive but are you so sure it is in MongoDB? Esepcially considering how $ors are run in MongoDB

Comment: @RobertoReale Yes it does. The approach being taken is the wrong approach. Queries in this form will never perform well. You need to use a different approach

Comment: An or in MongoDB is done by parallel querying whose results are then merged and returned, hence a $or can use more than one index