# mongo query sort and regex method in efficient way

Tags: mongodb

```
 db.location.find(
  { "$or": [ 
    { "country_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "country" }, 
    { "region_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "region" }, 
    { "city_lc": /^unit/, "docType": "city" } 
   ]}, 
   { "country": 1, "region": 1, "city": 1, "docType" :1 }
 ).sort({ "country_lc" :1, "region_lc": 1, "city_lc":1 })
```

this is query in monodb is taking very much time. How to query this efficiently ? Below is the explain() output of the above query. I have total 442161 documents in the collection location.I have to do some prefix searching.I have done indexing in (country_lc,docType)
,(region_lc,docType),(city_lc,docType) and (country_lc,region_lc,city_lc)

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor country_lc_1_region_lc_1_city_lc_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 29,
"nscannedObjects" : 76935,
"nscanned" : 442161,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 76935,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 442161,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 79,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 81531,
"indexBounds" : {
    "country_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "region_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ],
    "city_lc" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "prashanta:27017"
```

}

Comment: What MongoDB verison is this, there is a bug in versions before 2.6 which means an index cannot be used efficiently with sort and or

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb sort and regex query in efficient way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130882/mongodb-sort-and-regex-query-in-efficient-way)

Comment: I have just noticed @ChristianP is right, can you edit your old question with this and the MongoDB version rather than opening a new question?

Comment: Not even close. Don't listen to these people. Sorry you had to be exposed to this.